# SGE qsub concatenate different requests for different hosts

Tags: gridengine

I wonder it is possible to concatenate multiple requests for different hosts in SGE qsub command? For example, I tried this:

`qsub -l h="compute-0-[0-9]" -pe smp 6 -l h="compute-0-2[0-9]" -pe smp 4`

However, SGE will ignore the first `-l` and `-pe` argument. Is there a way to put an OR in the middle, like `-o` in `find` command? Thanks.